# Email from address changes once it is delivered

Tags: wordpress, email, bluehost

I am currently doing work for a client and am running into a bit of an issue when an email receipt is sent to the user.  What is happening is that once the email address is delivered the from address is completely different then the one I am using.  I have tried using a few different email addresses and they work fine.  It's only the one that they really want to use that is causing the problem.

I don't have access to their site and am also unsure of how the mail is sent.  What I am wondering is if anyone knows the questions that I can ask to figure out what is going on on there end.  They recently changed who was handling their site so I have a feeling something may be getting mixed up.

The site is built with WordPress and is using Gravity Forms.  From the changed email address I can see that they are using Bluehost since the email changes from @companyname to @boxXXX.bluehost.com.

Email servers are not my area of expertise so I really appreciate any help.

Comment: e-mail server at bluehost is most probably doing masquerading. Check this: http://serverfault.com/questions/28444/what-is-address-masquerading

Comment: Thanks that linked cleared a lot of things up. Can I ask how did you come to know about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Very likely their Wordpress website is sending emails through the `wp_mail()` function which is nothing more than the usual `mail()` function from PHP.

By default if you send an email through this method it will display either the hostname of the server where the website is sitting or the SMTP server, in this case boxXXX.bluehost.com depending on what's the policy of Bluehost regarding sending e-mails.

Generally hosting provider switch off the php mail() function in shared hosting environments to prevent spam and they provide you with the details to connect to their SMTP server and send legit e-mails, if their server is sitting on a shared hosting I think you might need support from Bluehost directly, explain to them the situation and they will help you throughout the process.

If the website is sitting on a virtual dedicated server then they need to do additional configuration on it. In this case what I do is to access onto cPanel and create a new mailbox with the address I want to send from (wordpress@domain.com, info@domain.com, whatever the client wants to be displayed) and configure Wordpress to send with through the VPS SMTP (you can do that easily with this nice plugin: http://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-mail-smtp ) with the address and password you chose when creating the email account on cPanel.
From now on the email will show the correct address.

Also you might want to increase the deliverability of your message and to instruct the email servers that are receiving the email that you're using a legit account, so you should add to their DNS both [DKIM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DomainKeys_Identified_Mail) and [SPF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sender_Policy_Framework) server records.

**Note:** I suggest you to be extremely cautious when playing around with DNSes, especially when touching email related records. If you are not familiar on how setup new and change the current existing records ask for help from someone who has quite good experience and to guide you through the process so you understand how it works and the consequences of a bad formatted or clashing records.

We recently had a really bad couple of hours at work when someone touched the company records without any clue of what was doing and we ended up with no email and website working for several hours.

Comment: Thanks for the help.  I will let the client know about this.